# How to build perftest and run latency tests on RDMA

Tags: c, linux, performance-testing, microbenchmark, rdma

I'm trying to build the [perftest C library](https://github.com/linux-rdma) to run some latency tests over the RDMA protocol.

My steps:

- I downloaded the library from [their GitHub](https://github.com/linux-rdma) and unzipped it on the box on which I want to run the server for the tests
- I executed:

  `./autogen`

  `./configure`

  `make clean && make V=1`

- I tried to run a test

  `./ib_send_lat --duration=30 -H`

..but I get the **following error**:

```
Port number 1 state is Down
Couldn't set the link layer
Couldn't get context for the device
```

What am I doing wrong?

Running other tests that use the RDMA protocol (eg. [the ones in Accelio](https://github.com/accelio/accelio/tree/fd3c54c907a3e5d5f218361e0a596930afe826e4/tests/usr/hello_test_lat)) the system shows no problems.

Also, I runned a few diagnostic tools and everything seems configured correctly already:

- Verified that RDMA kernel part is loaded (*ibuverbs* present)
  [image]
- Verified that RDMA devices are available
  [image]
- Verified that RDMA devices can be accessed (the second one says PORT_ACTIVE)
  [image]
- Verified that traffic over RDMA is working sending messages from a client to a server using rping [image]

Any suggestions? (I opened an [issue](https://github.com/linux-rdma/perftest/issues/43) on their GitHub but I got no reply yet)

Thanks

Comment: Argh, so many images. Please don't post text as images. Please don't post images, unless they are images. How do you think people on mobile devices will see your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is the perftest tools are defaulting to using the device  that's in the PORT_DOWN state.

Try specifying the specific device to use with the '-d' option. eg:

```
ib_send_lat -d mlx5_0 ...
```

(This will probably need to be done on both sides of the link.)

Comment: That worked! :)
Awesome, I'll thank you with a 100 bounty as soon as it becomes available

Comment: 100 bounty added -> "You may award your bounty in 23 hours."